# No non-trivial clopen sets in $\mathbb{R}$? How to give a direct proof?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

How to give a direct proof of the following result?

> Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A$ is both open and closed. Then $A$ is either empty or all of $\mathbb{R}$?

My work:

If $A$ is not empty, let $u \in A$. Then there is some open interval $(a,b)$ such that $$u \in (a,b) \subset A.$$

Now if $\mathbb{R} - A$ is not empty either, then let $v \in \mathbb{R} - A$. Then there is some open interval $(c,d)$ such that 
$$v \in (c,d) \subset \mathbb{R} - A.$$

Suppose that $u < v$.

Since $$\emptyset \subset (a,b) \cap (c,d) \subset A \cap (\mathbb{R} - A) = \emptyset,$$
we must have $$(a,b) \cap (c,d) = \emptyset.$$
So we can conlclude that $$b \leq c.$$
But $b \in A$ and $c \in \mathbb{R} - A$. So we must have $$b < c.$$

What next? Can anybody here please help complete the proof from here on?

An edit based on a comment by Marc Paul:

Let us assume that the set $A$ is a non-trivial clopen set in $\mathbb{R}$. Let us define a function $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as follows: 
$$f(x) \colon= \begin{cases} 1 \ \mbox{ for } \ x \in A; \\ 0 \ \mbox{ for } \ x \in \mathbb{R} - A. \end{cases}$$

Let $V$ be an open set in the range space $\mathbb{R}$. We show that the inverse image set $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in the domain space $\mathbb{R}$.

The following cases arise:

If $0, 1 \in V$, then $f^{-1}(V) = \mathbb{R}$.

If $0 \in V$ but $1 \not\in V$, then $f^{-1}(V) = \mathbb{R} - A$.

If $1 \in V$ but $0 \not\in V$, then $f^{-1}(V) = A$.

And, if $0 \not\in V$ and $1 \not\in V$, then $f^{-1}(V) = \emptyset$.

Thus, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in the domain space $\mathbb{R}$.

Hence the function $f$ is continuous.

What next? How does this lead to our desired conclusion?

[Yet another edit, again based on valuable comments from Marc Paul: ]

So if both $A$ and $\mathbb{R} - A$ were non-empty, then let's suppose $a \in A$ and $b \in \mathbb{R} - A$, and we can assume without any loss of generality that $a < b$.

Then $f(a) = 1$ and $f(b) = 0$. So by the intermediate value theorem there is a real number $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c) = 1/2$, which is a contradiction because the image set of $f$ does not contain $1/2$.

Comment: What sort of **indirect** proof did you have in mind?

Comment: @bof since $\mathbb{R}$, being a linear continuum, is connected, so the only clopen subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are the empty set and $\mathbb{R}$ itself.

Comment: You could consider the indicator function on $A$, and prove that it is continuous.

Comment: @bof is the argument I've started in my original going to lead me to a proof, I wonder?

Comment: @MarcPaul could you please complete the argument I've started in my original post? I've managed to fill in the details of your hint.

Comment: @MarcPaul can you please have a look at my question again now?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud We know that $\mathbb Q$ is not connected, so any proof of connectedness of $\mathbb R$ uses some property of $\mathbb R$ that $\mathbb Q$ doesn't have. In the answers below the property is the least-upper-bound property and in my suggestion it would be the intermediate value theorem. In other words, there is no 'easy' way to complete your argument, you really need some 'hard' properties of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud after your edit, use the intermediate value theorem to finish the proof.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assume for a contradiction that $A$ is a clopen subset of $\mathbb R,\ $ $\emptyset\ne A\ne\mathbb R.$ Choose $a\in A$ and $b\in\mathbb R\setminus A.$ Without loss of generality, we may assume that $a\lt b.$

Let $c=\sup(A\cap[a,b]).$ Since $A$ is closed we have $c\in A,$ and so $a\le c\lt b.$ Now $c\in A$ and $(c,b]\subseteq\mathbb R\setminus A,$ contradicting the assumption that $A$ is open.

Comment: Why we have contradiction with $A$ is open ?

Comment: The fact that $(c,b]\subseteq\mathbb R\setminus A$ while $c\notin\mathbb R\setminus A$ tells us that $\mathbb R\setminus A$ is not closed, which means that $A$ is notr open.

Comment: Since every open interval containing $c$ must intersect $(c, b]$.

Answer (score 0):

We assume, seeking a contradiction, that $A$ is a non trivial clopen set.
Let $u \in A$ and consider the family
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F} = \{ \ I \ : \  u \in I  \ \text{ and } I \subset A \text{ is an open interval }\}.
\end{equation}

The union  $J = \bigcup\mathcal{F}$ is still an open interval contained in $A$. So $J = (a, b)$ for some $a < u < b$ where $a$ or $b$ is a real number (not plus or minus infinity). Now assume w.l.o.g. that $b \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $b \in \mathbb{R} \setminus A$. Since $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$ is open, there must be  an open interval $B$ contained in $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$ containing $b$. But then $B \cap A \ne \emptyset$. And this is a contradiction.