# Proof Explanation - $\Bbb R$ is connected, i.e. has no non-trivial clopen subsets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation

I know that $\Bbb R$ is connected iff it has no non-trivial clopen subsets. To show that $\Bbb R$ has no non-trivial clopen subsets, I came across the following solution which I need help in understanding.

> Assume for a contradiction that $A$ is a clopen subset of $\mathbb R,\ $ $\emptyset\ne A\ne\mathbb R.$ Choose $a\in A$ and $b\in\mathbb R\setminus A.$ Without loss of generality, we may assume that $a\lt b.$ Let $c=\sup(A\cap[a,b]).$ Since $A$ is closed we have $c\in A,$ and so $a\le c\lt b.$ Now $c\in A$ and $(c,b]\subseteq\mathbb R\setminus A,$ contradicting the assumption that $A$ is open.

(Cited from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1628995/30222).)

I have some questions:

1. What motivated the choice $c=\sup(A\cap[a,b])$?
2. *Since $A$ is closed, we have $c\in A$* - why is that? (Once $c\in A$, we know that $c\neq b$ and in fact $c < b$. Since $c$ is $\sup$ of $A\cap[a,b]$, $c \ge a$ is also clear).
3. Why is $(c,b]\subseteq\mathbb R\setminus A$, and how does it contradict the assumption that $A$ is open?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you cite another post (or any other source) verbatim, you should include a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What motivated the choice $c=\sup(A \cap [a,b])$?

The proof basically chooses a point in $A$ ($a$) and a point outside it ($b$). The goal of the proof here is to look at what happens as you go from $a$ to $b$, because you have to "get out" of the set $A$ in some sense. The contradiction arises from the fact that the "edge" of the set cannot be both open and closed. (Obviously this explanation is not meant to be rigorous, but I think it motivates the choice nicely)

> Since $A$ is closed, we have $c \in A$

Because closed sets contain all of their boundary points, and the set $A \cap [a,b]$ is closed (as it is the intersection of two closed sets), and its supremum is its boundary point

> Why is $(c,b] \subseteq \mathbb R \setminus A$

Because $c$ was the defined as the supremum of $[a,b] \cap A$, so if $(c, b]$ contained more points from $A$, then $c$ wouldn't be the supremum

> and how does it contradict the assumption that $A$ is open?

We saw that $c$ is in $A$, and $A$ is assumed to be open, meaning that every point in $A$ (including $c$) has an open ball around it that is still within $A$. But you can see that there can be no such ball, because for any $r > 0$, $c + r$ is already not in the set $A$

Comment: The supremum is *not always* the limit point - so how would you argue here? eg. $A = \{a\}$ and $\sup A = a$. The rest of it seems good! It'd be nice if you could help *prove* that $\sup$ is actually the limit point here.

Comment: That *is* a limit point, though. I say that $x$ is a limit point of $A$ if for any $r > 0$, the open ball $B(x,r)$ will conatain elements from both $A$ and $\mathbb R \setminus A$, and that is fulfilled in your example with the singleton set. (It might not be the usual terminology though, I didn't learn real analysis in English)

Comment: Oh, I see, no problem! The definition of **limit points** I know is: "Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.  A point $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is called a [*limit point*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) of $A$ if for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists some $y\ne x$ such that $|y-x| < \varepsilon$ and $y\in A$.  In other words, every $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $A$ which is **different from** $x$." Maybe you're talking about **adherent points!**

Comment: $\sup A$ is always an adherent point of $A$, so unless you claim that *"closed sets contain all their adherent points"* - I'm afraid this part needs more clarification. Can you help, please?

Comment: It seems that what I meant is called **boundary points** in English

Comment: That does the job! I used that *a closed set contains all its boundary points* with *$\sup S$ is a boundary point of $S$ if $S\subset\Bbb R$ is non-empty and bounded*.